# FCE exam's troubling transformation sentence

Tags: grammar

Today my students were given the following transformation sentence as part of their FCE exams:

> I am reading a book which is irrelevant to school work.

Do:

The book I am reading **is** ..................... school work.

Can you please tell me how to do it?

The obvious would be:

> The book I am reading **has** nothing to do with school work.

But the exercise asks us to use *is*, not *has*.

Comment: ELL is a better site for this question.

Comment: @Mitch And even better for the answers and comments.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest answer is this:

> The book I am reading is **irrelevant to** school work.

Comment: But could that really be what the question wants you to do? It would be...trivial.

Comment: @Cerberus: Yes, that's the answer that the question wants. How do I know? I'm a long-time EFL teacher. The [FCE](http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/exams-and-qualifications/first/) is the First Certificate in English exam. [This is the kind of stuff they ask](http://www.flo-joe.co.uk/fce/students/tests/). It's not difficult if you're a native speaker. What it's asking the testee to do is to rephrase the sentence without a relative pronoun & clause: say the same thing in slightly different words. What else could the question be asking? Trivial? Yes & no. Only native & fluent speakers can do this.

Comment: I'm afraid you've got the right of it, Bill. I've taken a lot of exams in my life, and the one thing I've learned is not to overestimate the subtlety of questions of standardized exams. That's not what they're for.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Right. Standardized exams are hurdles created for the sake of creating hurdles. They become a cottage industry, then a big business, then a major player in the WTO as well as the domestic economy. I consider them to be in the same league as the betel nut business here in Taiwan. Everyone knows chewing betel nuts causes oral cancer & growing betel nut palms guarantees soil erosion & landslides during typhoons & torrential rains, but too many Taiwanese earn a living by hawking them. Big ESL, meet Big Tobacco & Big Betel Nuts. Homozygous triplets. :-)

Comment: All right, if you say so. I wasn't sure because I have never seen such a trivial transformation in a test, but I have less experience than you.

Answer (score 0):

The book I am reading **is** nothing to do with (my) school work. (!)

from Collins at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nothing :

**have** or **be nothing to do with**: to have no connection with

Comment: Wow! But take a look at Google Ngram Viewer for those phrases: "0" of "is nothing to do with". [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) shows 15 vs. 2413 for _is_ vs. _has_. I doubt that the FCE will accept "The book I am reading **is** nothing to do with school work." "The book I am reading is irrelevant to school work." is still the better answer: shorter & uses the same word (_irrelevant_) as the original S. That's how test-makers think. I couldn't reach the [BNC](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) because of constant timeouts.

Comment: So 250 000 (admittedly raw} Google hits for "is nothing to do with" means nothing to them!

Comment: Correct! Those who construct standardized tests are not egalitarians or politically liberal linguistic descriptivists. They believe that there are right & wrong ways of using the language in every instance. These are the actual members of the Academy that John Lawler constantly dismisses as phantoms. They're all Freemasons & certifiable relatives of Sophie Neveu, the heroine of _The Da Vinci Code_, who is a direct descendant, if you remember, of Jesus & Mary Magdalene. Therefore, what they say has the force of divine right: they are the grammar gods.

Comment: The book I am reading is more fun than school work. And probably makes better sense.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but making sense isn't the point: _Tell me what I'm thinking!_ is what most standardized tests are about. Good, clear, understandable, idiomatic English isn't what it's about: _Give me the answer I want!_ is the rule.